# list template doesn't appear in some sub sites

Tags: sharepoint-server

I created List template in sub-site, and started to use it in all our sub-sites seamlessly, except for few sub-sites I cannot find this particular template
I checked the enabled and disabled features for both working and non-working sub-sites, but both showing the same
Any idea what else I need to check?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enable the "Team Colloboration List" feature in the subsite from site settings > Manage site features?

Check if the template has different language than the issue subsites.

If the template is in a team site, then it cannot be used in a publishing site.

Re-save this list as a template and do not select "include contents" option. Then compare the results.

Also check if below article is useful to you:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/4d2336be-2b05-4ce2-887a-5f68d8e60a81/list-template-doesnt-appear-in-sub-sites?forum=sharepointadminlegacy

Comment: Dear Allen,
1- yes the "Team Colloboration List" featureis enabled
2- same language being used
3- I did saved the template without its contents,
let me explain more, i have almost 30+subsite under the root, i used the same teplate for all of them, except this one the template doesnt appear, all of them were created with the same Department template and having the same master page.
please advise

Comment: Are you using a same machine? 
Ensure that the Features enabled in your source subsite also enabled in your issue subsite.
Also try to test in another browser.

Answer (score 0):

Go to site settings -> Language settings and check the default language.
Check the other sub sites default language as well and make similar, may be it will help to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you check if the template's language is different from the language on the child sites, this is a very important nuance. You also need to go to the site settings and check if the "Manage site functions" function is enabled there. If you have checked all this information, then I recommend that you try creating another new template and try opening it through a subsite. When I had such a problem, I found a template on this site https://www.listtemplate.net/ and everything worked out for me. I hope you solve your problem.